# plot every n-th label in the legend in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some graphs to plot, each with contours. Is there a way to plot every 2nd label in the key? The number of contours I get makes them look cluttered. I don't mean setting `notitle` when plotting.

I saved my contour data in a file using the `table` terminal, so it is all indexed in the file. I'm using the following to plot the contours:

```
splot "some_data", "contours.dat" index 0 title "Title 1", "" index 1 title "Title 2"
```

and so on for any number of indices (I don't know how many there will be for each data file). The above is generated using a script, so I guess I could add `notitle` to every other index (which would take a few lines of code), but was wondering if there is a cleaner method?